# Is it ok to ask for a refernece for stress-strain curve data?

Tags: discussion

So I need to find data from a tensile test of a steel (any steel), I need a curve with "a lot of points", not just the usually important ones. Is it ok to ask for that in the main site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't ask for this. At its base level, it is a [resource hunting question](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10/33). These questions are not a good fit here because they typically grow stale as they get older.

With the being said, this information should exist somewhere. I know for a fact it is in my old Mechanics of Materials class notebook from years ago.

If there is a more broad question that you are trying to solve, **that** question may be a good fit for the site instead of asking for the data to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, there is not underlaying question, I need it to construct some examples.